# SQL database front end data input form

Tags: sql, asp.net, web

I have a TSQL database and for the sake of simplicity I created one table called staffrecords with the fields (StaffID, FirstName, Surname, DateofBirth)

I require something where my client can enter data into and will go into the database instantly. So instead of doing insert querys or typing data into the database they can have a front end online application and submit it like that.

Can you guys advise will be the above requirements and point me in the right direction.

Comment: There are many ways to build a UI. Web is probalby the most complicated. The least complicated would be using MS Access as a front end. You have tagged asp.net. Does that mean you want to build a fron end in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by instantly. As far as I know, the only way to get Data into an SQL Database are the two methods you described above: `INSERT` statements and typing it into the database directly. If you want to remove a little bit of latency on getting the data into the database on the front end, I would recommend using AJAX in order to add data to the database as the user types it into the front end interface.

E.g.,

- User opens the form page: send a message to a server side script telling it to make a new row.
- User enters their StaffID: AJAX this information and fill out the appropriate cell in the database using a `REPLACE` command.
- etc., etc.

Obviously, periodically the database will have to scan for empty rows and remove them as these can result from the user visiting the page but not entering any data. A workaround to this could be only creating the row when the *first* field is filled out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes i wanted a form of some sort which can be online like a website maybe where they can enter a new staff record and it will go into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I developed this code to execute a sample to insert the data into the database.

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="demo";
    

    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    //CHECK CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
    }
    //$sql="INSERT INTO student(CATEGORY_NAME) VALUES ('Grapes')";

    //isset();

    //Die();
    if (isset($_POST["add"])) 
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO category(CATEGORY_ID,CATEGORY_NAME) VALUES ('','".$_POST["CATEGORY_NAME"]."')";

        //echo $sql;

        //die();

        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if ($result===TRUE) 
        {
            echo"NEW RECORD CREATED SUCCESSFULLY";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR:".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
        }   
    }   
    $conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CATEGORY</title>
</head>

<body align="center">
<div>
<form action="" method="POST">
<td align="center" bgcolor="lightblue"><b>CATEGORY:</b><input type="value" name="CATEGORY_NAME" WIDTH="1000" value=""/></td>
</br>
</br>
<button type="submit" name="add" value="add">ADD</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```